# Why does a blue box appears in my slider slide

Tags: jquery, css, xml, slider

I've created a slider that loads the content from an XML file. If there is no image added, it prints the text "Photo available soon", if there is an image, it shows the image.

You can check it out at: http://theguest.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/#the-guests

I've only added an image to the second element in the XML. But all the other elements, it shows a box blue. I don't see where that comes from. I also cannot inspect that element.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The blue box is related to the Background color of the following element:

```
<div class="slider slick-initialized slick-slider" id="slider"></div>
```

CSS

```
.slider {
    background-color: #00f;
    border: 3px solid #d0de36;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 20rem;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The height of this element is being set by one of the children elements:

```
<div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 314px;" tabindex="-1"><div><div class="slider__slide" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;"><img src="img/guests/aion.jpg"><span class="name">Aion</span></div></div></div>
```

This has a height of 415 pixels.